# Splashscreen animation flicker when updated in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, splash-screen, flicker

I have a Java application that uses a splash screen image with a loading animation. The splashscreen is painted every x ms from within the Java code.

Running the application on Windows, works flawlessly with no flickering. However, when running on OSX, the splash screen flickers every time I run `splash.update()` from the Java code.

The flicker is very subtle, but annoying, so I really want to fix it.

I have tried to call `spalsh.update()` with different speeds, but the flicker remains.

Does anybody have a clue why this happens?

```
@Override
public void run(){
     final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
     if (splash == null) {
         System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
         return;
     }
     Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
     if (g == null) {
         System.out.println("g is null");
         return;
     }
   while(true) {
         //...
         //Here some animation happens. But the flicker is still there when I 
         //comment this out so the problem lies elsewhere
         //...
         splash.update(); //THIS CAUSES THE FLICKER ON macOS

         try {
             Thread.sleep(75);
         }
         catch(InterruptedException e) {
         }
         if (GUI.frame != null){
             if (GUI.frame.isVisible()){
                 splash.close();
                 break;
             }   
         }               
     }
}
```

Comment: *"Do anybody have a clue why this happens?"* Probably the code. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok done. @Andrew

Comment: *"Ok done."* I can only conclude that either you did not read, or did not understand, the two linked documents.